# POSTGRESQL: Weighted average instead of average?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, average

I have a list of averages

```
SELECT tv.id, AVG(ut.rating) FROM user_tvshow AS ut
LEFT JOIN tvshows AS tv ON tv.id = ut.tvshow
WHERE "user" IN (
    SELECT follows FROM user_follows WHERE "user" = 1   -- List of users the current user follows
) AND rating IS NOT NULL GROUP BY tv.id;
```

At the moment it averages the results as expected. Is there any way to weight this average with the number of rows in the group? So that one row of rating 10 won't appear higher than 100 rows of rating 9.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  This doesn't sound like a "weighted average".

Comment: You could also attatch db schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what a weighted average is.  It sounds like you are trying to get at a [Bayesian average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average) where you penalize a small set by moving its observed average towards some meta-average.  There is no built in way to do this in PostgreSQL.

Compute the sum and count separately, and then use some mechanism to implement the penalty based on those values.  You could do that in the client, or you could write an outer query which takes the results of the subquery and applies the formula.

```
select id, (the_sum + 10* <metaaveerage>)/(the_count+10) from (
    SELECT tv.id, sum(ut.rating) as the_sum, count(ut.rating) as the_count FROM user_tvshow AS ut
    LEFT JOIN tvshows AS tv ON tv.id = ut.tvshow
    WHERE "user" IN (
       SELECT follows FROM user_follows WHERE "user" = 1   -- List of users the current user follows
    ) AND rating IS NOT NULL GROUP BY tv.id
) foobar
```

How you decide what values to plug in for the `10` and for the `<metaaverage>` are questions of statistics, not programming.